# Can a javascript function return a struct type

Tags: javascript

I have java background and dealing with javascript is not a very pleasing experience.
I would like to write a function which receives an array of 2d points (x,y) and returns again another array of 2d points. In Java i can define Class, say C2DPoints, and use in my function definition as in input argument type and as the output type as well. But, What would be the best approach to dealing with this issue in javascript?

my solution:

```
function scale2D(x,y, scaleX, scaleY){
    // primitives x, y are passed by value

    for (i=0;i< x.length;i++){
        x[i] = x[i]*scaleX;
        y[i] = y[i]*scaleY;
    }
    return [x,y];
}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? Anything at all?

Comment: You could return an object, e.g. `{x: 5, y: 6}`, or simply an array, `[5, 6]`, but JavaScript doesn't have type annotations, if that's what you are asking about.

Comment: @CoreyOgburn, no I didnt do anything, I am siting here eating popcorn and pressing F5 every minute! Of course I did, but did not like the ugly way I got around this issue, what is the point of sharing a wrong answer!

Comment: @Cgraphics You'd be surprised at the number of people who have done jack squat for their question(s) on this site. Even if it's a wrong answer, sharing it will give us a *much* better idea of how you're thinking about the problem and your level of knowledge with JavaScript. At the very least, there's no *harm* in sharing your code attempt.

Comment: @ajp15243 I edited the question and added my solution. Now will you help me?

Comment: How are you calling the function?

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways... try something in jsfiddle.

```
//Taking in 2 numbers
var newArr = function(x,y){
  var a = x+1,
      b = y+1;
  return [a,b];
}
console.log(newArr(1,1));
// Will echo: [2,2]


//Taking in an array of 2 numbers
var newArr = function(x){
  var a = x[0]+1,
      b = x[1]+1;
  return [a,b];
}
console.log(newArr([1,1]));
// Will echo: [2,2]

// Taking in an object
var newArr = function(obj){
  var a = obj.x+1,
      b = obj.y+1;
  return [a,b];
}
console.log( newArr({x:1,y:1}) );
// Will echo: [2,2]

// Accept an Obj and return an Obj
var newArr = function(obj){
  var a = obj.x+1,
      b = obj.y+1;
  return {a:a,b:b};
}
console.log( newArr({x:1,y:1}) );
// Will echo: {a:2,b:2}
```

Comment: On the first example newArr [0] returns a, right. Is there a better way to access a? something like newArr.a?

Comment: A better way? Not without going through the trouble of instantiating an object. (see below answer)

Comment: In JS we now have access to `for...of` as well as destructors: `const {a} = newArr(args)` assuming an object literal is returned.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely, look into JavaScript Object Literal Notation.  In fact, you don't even have to create classes in JavaScript, you can create objects in a function and give them the functions you want them to have during construction.

```
 function main() {
    var myGuy = returner();
    myGuy.sayAge();
 }

 function returner() {
    return {
       name: "bob",
       age: "99",
       sex: "m",
       sayAge: function() {
          console.log(this.age);
       }
    };
 }
```

In terms of your example though, you could still go ahead and take the OOP approach and make a sort of Point class.

```
 function main() {
    var points = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
       points.push(new Point2D(i, i + 1));
    }

    manipArray(points);

    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
       console.log("Point: " + i + " x: " + points[i].x + " y: " + points[i].y);
    }
 }

 function Point2D(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
 }
 Point2D.prototype.add = function(other) {
    this.x += other.x;
    this.y += other.y;
 }

 function manipArray(arrOfPoints) {

    var myPoint = new Point2D(4, 5);

    for (var i = 0; i < arrOfPoints.length; i++) {
       arrOfPoints[i].add(myPoint);
    }
 }
```

When `main()` runs it will give you:

```
Point: 0 x: 4 y: 6 (12:48:07:947)
Point: 1 x: 5 y: 7 (12:48:07:952)
Point: 2 x: 6 y: 8 (12:48:07:956)
Point: 3 x: 7 y: 9 (12:48:07:958)
Point: 4 x: 8 y: 10 (12:48:07:959)
Point: 5 x: 9 y: 11 (12:48:07:961)
Point: 6 x: 10 y: 12 (12:48:07:962)
Point: 7 x: 11 y: 13 (12:48:07:963)
Point: 8 x: 12 y: 14 (12:48:07:964)
Point: 9 x: 13 y: 15 (12:48:07:965)
```

Which means the points that you passed have been changed within the function as an `out` parameter of sorts.  Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: It seems you are confusing JavaScript object literals (constructs of the JavaScript language syntax) with JSON (a language-independent data-exchange format, like XML or CSV). The value you return from `retuner` is an **object**, specified as **object literal/initializer**. It is not JSON.

Comment: @FelixKling I did not know that, thank you for explaining it.  I have changed my answer to reflect your comment.  I'm off to learn more about the differences.

Comment: @zero298 Thank you but 1) I am looking for a return statement to clearly state what the manipArray returns ! 2) I am expecting the input of  manipArray(points); be of type Point2D, points is not of type Point2D

Comment: @Cgraphics JavaScript doesn't really have a built-in way to specify what type of object you are going to return.  You could add an attribute to the thing you return that you check in the calling function to be sure that it's what you want, but there is no `public int myFunc(String a){return 8;}` like you are used to in Java.  Also, you said that you wanted a function that would receive an array and then return an array so I'm not following your second point.

Comment: @zero298 my second question was only about understanding consistency here

Answer (score 0):

```
//Taking in 2 numbers as an Object
const newArr = function(x,y){
  this.x = x+1,
  this.y = y+2;
},
const Arr = new newArr(1,1);
console.log(Arr.x);
// Will echo: 2
console.log(Arr.y);
// Will echo: 3
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want struct types for performance or compatibility you should look at [TypedArrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Typed_arrays) and [DataViews](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DataView).

In this sample code I benchmark TypedArrays and other common techniques.

I verified no v8 jit deopts occur in timed code.

Consistent benchmark times in node 8.5:

```
A:  4.431ms          [TypedArray([x1,y1]), TypedArray([x2,y2]), ...]
B:  2.655ms          TypedArray(x1, y1, x2, y2, ...)
C:  4.454ms          [[x1,y1], [x2,y2], ...]
D:  5.917ms          [x1, y1, x2, y2, ...]
E: 80.101ms          [{x1,y1}, {x2,y2}, ...] (as .x and .y)
```

And in Chrome 70, with moderate fluctuations:

```
A: 4.19999985024333ms
B: 2.79999990016222ms
C: 4.800000227987766ms
D: 3.8999998942017555ms
E: 33.19999994710088ms
```

You can run the snippet to see times for your browser.

```js
// technique A : js array of TypedArray points

const count = 100 * 1000;

function Point(x, y) {
    return Float32Array.from([x, y]);
}

function scale1(points, scaleX, scaleY) {
    for (let i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
        points[i][0] *= scaleX;
        points[i][1] *= scaleY;
    }
}

function init1() {
    let points = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        points[i] = Point(i, count - i);
    }
    return points;
}

function test1() {
    let points = init1();
    let start = performance.now();
    scale1(points, 1.2, 1.8);
    let delta = performance.now() - start;
    document.write('A: ', delta, 'ms<br>');
}

// technique B : TypedArray of consecutive xy values

function scale2(values, scaleX, scaleY) {
    for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        values[i * 2] *= scaleX;
        values[i * 2 + 1] *= scaleY;
    }
}

function init2() {
    let points = new Float32Array(count * 2);
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        points[i * 2] = i;
        points[i * 2 + 1] = count - i;
    }
    return points;
}

function test2() {
    let points = init2();
    let start = performance.now();
    scale2(points, 1.2, 1.8);
    let delta = performance.now() - start;
    document.write('B: ', delta, 'ms<br>');
}

// technique C : js array of js point arrays

function scale3(points, scaleX, scaleY) { // same as A
    for (let i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
        // jit chokes on *= here, but not in A
        //   probably because A uses a TypedArray underneath
        //points[i][0] *= scaleX;
        //points[i][1] *= scaleY;
        points[i][0] = points[i][0] * scaleX;
        points[i][1] = points[i][1] * scaleY;
    }
}

function init3() {
    return init1(); // jit deopts (lazy) if init3() is duplicate of init1()
}

function test3() {
    let points = init3();
    let start = performance.now();
    scale3(points, 1.2, 1.8);
    let delta = performance.now() - start;
    document.write('C: ', delta, 'ms<br>');    
}

// technique D : js array of js numbers

function scale4(values, scaleX, scaleY) { // same as B
    for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        values[i * 2] *= scaleX;
        values[i * 2 + 1] *= scaleY;
    }
}

function init4() {
    let points = [];
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        points[i * 2] = i;
        points[i * 2 + 1] = count - i;
    }
    return points;
}

function test4() {
    let points = init4();
    let start = performance.now();
    scale4(points, 1.2, 1.8);
    let delta = performance.now() - start;
    document.write('D: ', delta, 'ms<br>');
}

// technique E : js array of js objects

function scale5(points, scaleX, scaleY) { // same as A
    for (let i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
        points[i].x = points[i].x * scaleX;
        points[i].y = points[i].y * scaleY;
    }
}

function init5() {
    let points = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        points[i] = { x: i, y: count - i };
    }
    return points;
}

function test5() {
    let points = init5();
    let start = performance.now();
    scale5(points, 1.2, 1.8);
    let delta = performance.now() - start;
    document.write('E: ', delta, 'ms<br>');
}

// main

function main() {
    test1();
    test2();
    test3();
    test4();
    test5();
}

main();
```

```html
<p>Node benchmark times for a few different techniques:</p>

<pre>
A:  4.431ms          [TypedArray([x1,y1]), TypedArray([x2,y2]), ...]
B:  2.655ms          TypedArray(x1, y1, x2, y2, ...)
C:  4.454ms          [[x1,y1], [x2,y2], ...]
D:  5.917ms          [x1, y1, x2, y2, ...]
E: 80.101ms          [{x1,y1}, {x2,y2}, ...] (as .x and .y)
</pre>

<p><b>Browser benchmark times will display on run.</b></p>
```